# Delete all Subscriber from a Supression List

Tags: marketing-cloud, list

I'm trying to remove all subscribers from a suppression list, I have been able to get one in particular to be deleted, but I have not been able to do it for all of them. How could it be done? Thanks in advance

```
    var req = api.retrieve("List", 
    ["ListName", "ID"],
    {
        Property: "ListName",
        SimpleOperator: "equals",
        Value: "MySuppressionList"
    }
);

var listId = req.Results[0].ID;

var res = api.updateItem("Subscriber", {
    SubscriberKey: "XXXXXXXXXX",
    EmailAddress: "XXXXXXXXXXX",
    Lists: [
        {
            ID: listId,
            Action: "delete"
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`deleteItem`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_WSProxy_delete.html) function to remove a subscriber from the specified list, thus here is the script that will do the job -

```js
<script runat = "server">
    Platform.Load("Core", "1");
    var api = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

    var req = api.retrieve("List", 
        ["ListName", "ID"],
        {
            Property: "ListName",
            SimpleOperator: "equals",
            Value: "xxx"
        }
    );
    var listId = req.Results[0].ID;

    var res = api.deleteItem("Subscriber", {
        SubscriberKey: "xxx",
        EmailAddress: "xxx",
        Lists: [
            {
                ID: listId
            }
        ]
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But, how could i delete all the subscribers of a list? Thank you!

Comment: Then, it will be a totally different script that will retrieve all subscribers within the list and, based on the number of subscribers, iterate through all of them and delete them one by one with the same `deleteItem` function.